# How can I copy all files from multiple folder into a folder in realtime

Tags: windows-10, batch-file

My file structure looks like this

```
C:\photo1\2018-07-26\*.jpg
C:\photo1\2018-07-27\*.jpg
C:\photo1\2018-07-30\*.jpg

C:\photo2\2018-07-26\*.jpg
C:\photo2\2018-07-27\*.jpg
C:\photo2\2018-07-30\*.jpg
```

New files will add in the lastest date folder.
I am trying to copy all files into a folder without sub folders

```
C:\photo1\*\*.jpg -> C:\allphoto1\*.jpg
C:\photo2\*\*.jpg -> C:\allphoto2\*.jpg
```

and in realtime when new file added. 
Anyone know how to do this with a batch file or other software?

Comment: A clue ;)https://www.raymond.cc/blog/3-portable-tools-monitor-files-folders-changes/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to see if it helps.

```
cd /d "C:\photo1"  
for /r %d in (*) do copy "%d" "C:\allphoto1"

cd /d "C:\photo2"  
for /r %d in (*) do copy "%d" "C:\allphoto2"
```

This will copy all the files in the **C:\photo1**, as well as the **files in the subfolders** in **C:\photo1** to **C:\allphoto1**

Or you can move, replace, too.

```
cd /d "C:\photo1"  
for /r %d in (*) do *move* "%d" "C:\allphoto1"
```

---

Update:
You can use the following **test.bat** file, and just edit the **test.bat** and change the path as your requirement.

```
@echo off  
@cd /d c:\photo1  
@for /r %%d in (*) do move "%%d" "C:\allphoto1"  
@cd /d c:\photo2  
@for /r %%d in (*) do move "%%d" "C:\allphoto2"  
@pause
```

just create a new txt file, and type the above commands, and save as test.bat.
When you what to move them, just run it.

[image]
————————————————————————————————————————————

Or you can use this powershell script.

```
[CmdletBinding()]  
param  
(  
[parameter(Mandatory=$true)]  
[string]$sourcepath,  
[parameter(Mandatory=$true)]  
[string]$destinition  
)  
Write-Verbose "copy from one path to another path"

Get-ChildItem $sourcepath | ForEach-Object -Process{  
if($_ -is [System.IO.FileInfo])  
{  
Copy-Item  -Literalpath ( $_.PSpath )  -Destination   $destinition -force  -Recurse   
}  
}
```

Write-Verbose "scripts finished"

This script need to type the directory when running, and you can add the directory in the destination and sourcepath.

Comment: Can it be realtime?

Comment: This need to be run manually. Just double-click it when you want.

Comment: I have a little knowledge about the PS script. And if I can, I will modify this in the further.

Comment: Hard to read without using the `code` formatting :(

Comment: @VlastimilOvčáčík I am not good at using the code before, I will change it.